# How download in ubuntu with specific date?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, downloads

how can I download the contents of a website in Ubuntu considering the the time they are uploaded for example from 2012 on? (for example with `Wget` or ......)

Comment: What do you want to download? An old Ubuntu ISO version?

Comment: Content a web site .

Comment: You can't. Not unless you can find archived versions of this page somewhere. This is not a limitation of Ubuntu but of the internet itself. You can't do this in any OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://archive.org/web/web.php You can enter the address of the website and see whether snapshots of earlier versions are available.